# Updating a knockoutjs dropdown list and the knockout value using jQuery

Tags: knockout.js

Using knockoutJs I have a simple select on a page

```
<select id="voucherCountry" data-bind="options: availableCountries, optionsValue:'isoId', optionsText: 'country', value:selectedCountry"></select>
```

In the view model I have

```
function searchViewModel()
{
    var self = this;
    self.voucherNumber = ko.observable();
    self.selectedCountry = ko.observable();
    self.availableCountries = ko.observableArray(
        [
            new Country(250, 'France'),
            new Country(276, 'Germany'),
            new Country(724, 'Spain'),
            new Country(380, 'Italy'),
            new Country(826, 'United Kingdom')
        ])
```

and

```
function Country(iso, name)
{
    this.isoId = iso;
    this.country = name;
}
```

On the HTML page I want to be able to change the value of the drop-down and have the drop-down list show the new opton and have selectedCountry update in teh view model.

So I tried a simple jQuery statement

```
function changeCountry(isoId)
{
    $(voucherCountry).val(isoId);
}
```

which is called like so

```
changeCountry(380);
```

When I call this the text on the dropdown doesn't change, but when I click it to change the option the option I wanted to change it to is highlighted.

When I view what is helping the selectedCountry() variable it is set to the initial value, not the changed one.

So it seems it is updating the UI but not the view model.

I'm pretty sure there should be a simple solution to this, but I'm not getting it

**UPDATE:**

Okay so now I have a button

```
<button type="button" data-theme="b" data-bind="click: scanBarcode">Scan Barcode</button>
```

and in the view model this function:

```
self.scanBarcode = function()
{
    self.selectedCountry(380);
}
```

selectedCountry is being updated but the UI is not.

I assume there is an issue with how I am using the optionsValue and value attributes in the `<select>` data-bind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your changeCountry method should be changing the value of the underlying observable that you have bound the select to:

```
function changeCountry(isoId)
{
    selectedCountry(isoId);
}
```

That should then update both, as far as I'm aware.

You will also need to pass the new id in as a string, as knockout may well be using the type equality comparer (===), and the value in the html will be a string.

Comment: I assumed the view should have no knowledge of the view model variables. I want to mimic the action of a user selecting an option, which would then update the view model variable. It seems wrong to me that a javascript function on the view should access the view model. Is this correct?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, to be honest. By using Knockout, you are binding the view (Html) to the view model, it's kinda the point of it. Is your changeCountry method on the view model, as that's where I put this kind of logic, which might be why it feels correct to me. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I see my mistake, I was using an example that had javascript embedded on the html page, and I was calling that instead of calling a view model function that updated the view model variable. Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, it looks correct, and matches up with the documentation, so I'm a little flummoxed at this, I'm afraid! The only possible thought is that you're using the id as a number everywhere, and the value in the option itself will be a string, so if knockout is doing a === comparison, that would fail. That's just a guess though!

Comment: Good guess! self.selectedCountry("380"); did the job. Thanks

Comment: Ah, excellent, I'll add that to the answer then, for my own use if nothing else!

Answer (score 1):

This block

```
function changeCountry(isoId)
{
    $(voucherCountry).val(isoId);
}
```

Has multiple possible issues.

First, `$(voucherCountry)` probably doesn't evaluate to a valid selector; if you want to select the dropdown by id you'll need to do this: `$("#voucherCountry")`.

Then you can use `$("#voucherCountry").val(123)`.

The second thing that could be mixing things up is that you're modifying the UI as a way of indirectly modifying your viewmodel - you're probably better off updating your VM directly, as in `searchViewModel.selectedCountry(123)`

Comment: I see my mistake, I was using an example that had javascript embedded on the html page, and I was calling that instead of calling a view model function that updated the view model variable. Thanks for your help